# How to implement distance between different types in a pythonic way

Tags: python, polymorphism, overloading

Let's say I have different types like:

```
Point 
Circle 
Rectangle
Polyline
Circle_Collection
Rectangle_collection
```

etc

I want to be able to measure the distance between any combination of the types mentioned above. The easiest way would be to implement a distance method inside each of the classes:

```
class Point:
   def distance(self, other):
      if other is Point:
         # handle points
      if other is Circle:
         # handle circles
```

But then I thought it would be better to implement it as a free function because the distance to another objects is not really an inherent information about a class.

So lets say i would implement distance in a way that i can call it like

```
p = Point()
c = Cirle()
print distance(p,c)
```

What is the best way to do it? I have heard that function overloading isn't really a pythonic way to do things. What would be pythonically correct?

Comment: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)

Comment: I actually think distance **is** between two points. You should view other shapes as shapes composed of points. The distance between two shapes would be the distance between the two closest points between them.

Comment: Are you trying to measure between center points, or measure the distance between the closest points of each shape?

Comment: What exactly is the distance between a collection of circles and a collection of rectangles... I think you'll have to answer that first, and, depending on what that definition is, the answer to how it is calculated should be fairly straightforward...

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to do this yourself? OO issues aside, it becomes complicated quickly, and libraries like [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) cover this area extremely well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to measure the distance between midpoints of each shape, this question becomes much easier. Implement on some common ancestor `Shape`:

```
@property
def midpoint(self):
    """returns the midpoint of the shape as
    the tuple (x,y)"""
    # however you'll do this based on your structure
    #
    # note that if your shapes are immutable, you should make this
    # a regular attribute, not a property. I'm assuming your shapes
    # can move

@staticmethod
def distance(a, b):
    a_x, a_y = a.midpoint
    b_x, b_y = b.midpoint
    return (abs(a_x - b_x), abs(a_y - b_y))
```

You're right that finding the distance between two points is divorced somewhat from the object itself (i.e. an object shouldn't know how to find out its distance to another object), but it definitely does fit as something a Shape should know.

Run by calling

```
foo = Circle()
bar = Rectangle()

dist = Shape.distance(foo, bar)
```

Comment: The distance ist not between the center points, but between the closest points of two elements. I would use shapely if i could, but I also have to deal with elements which shapely doesn't cover, e.g. clothoids,